# How to calculate difficulty metric?

Tags: algorithm

**Note:** I have completely changed the original question!

I do have several texts, which consists of several words. Words are categorized into difficulty categories from 1 to 6, 1 being the easiest one and 6 the hardest (or from common to least common). However, obviously not all words can be put into these categories, because they are countless words in the english language.

Each category has twice as many words as the category before.

1. Level: 100 words in total (100 new)
2. Level: 200 words in total (100 new)
3. Level: 400 words in total (200 new)
4. Level: 800 words in total (400 new)
5. Level: 1600 words in total (800 new)
6. Level: 3200 words in total (1600 new)

When I use the term level 6 below, I mean **introduced** in level 6. So it is part of the 1600 new words and can't be found in the 1600 words up to level 5.

How would I rate the difficulty of an individual text? Compare these texts:

### An easy one

would only consist of very basic vocabulary:

```
I drive a car.
```

Let's say these are 4 level 1 words.

### A medium one

```
This old man is cretinous.
```

This is a very basic sentence which only comes with one difficult word.

### A hard one

would have some advanced vocabulary in there too:

```
I steer a gas guzzler.
```

So how much more difficult is the second or third of the first one? Let's compare text 1 and text 3. `I` and `a` are still level 1 words, `gas` might be lvl 2, `steer` is 4 and `guzzler` is not even in the list. `cretinous` would be level 6.
**How to calculate a difficulty of these texts, now that I've classified the vocabulary?**

I hope it is more clear what I want to do now.

Comment: I voted to reopen, but I still have doubts what you actually want done. Please consider rewriting the entire question.

Comment: I rewrote it now and hope it makes more sense now. If someone knows about this kind of stuff maybe I can edit appropriate terms into the question, so others can profit as well.

Comment: YOU need to think about what it means to combine words in a sentence. Your problem is one of definition, but that must come from you. Once that definition is available, then the answer will become trivial. Essentially this is a question maybe of linguistics or vaguely of mathematics, but not programming at all at this point.

Comment: For example, you might decide that words behave additively in a sentence. But does that make sense? Is a very short sentence with a terribly difficult word in it as bad as a long sentence from a Dr. Seuss book? And since it is you who decide very arbitrarily what category words fall into, this actual form is probably highly nonlinear. So your question is really impossible to answer, even as reformulated. Still too broad, and certainly off-topic as programming.

Comment: The combination of the words or grammar doesn't matter at all. Yes, I know I have to come up with a meaningful algorithm but that is exactly where I need help. Adding up scores for each word might not even be that bad. The thing with long sentences is, that when they just contain contain easy words you can at least recognize who is doing what. Complex sentence structures usually also require more advanced vocabulary.

Comment: But yes, actually I think it would better fit in mathematics. Should I post it there? Is there anything else that I should include?

Comment: Wow! Totally different question! Instead of changing a question so that it's totally different, you might be better off asking a new question (not edit, but submit a new question). This will keep comments and answers relevant to the original, while still asking the question you want to task.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are trying to solve is how to quantify your qualitative data.

The search term "quantifying qualitative data" may help you.

There is no general all-purpose algorithm for this. The best way to do it will depend upon what you want to use the metric for, and what your ratings of each individual task mean for the project as a whole in terms of practical impact on the factors you are interested in.

For example if the hardest tasks are typically unsolvable, then as soon as a project involves a single type 6 task, then the project may become unsolvable, and your metric would need to reflect this.

You also need to find some way to address the missing data (unrated tasks). It's likely that a single numeric metric is not going to capture all the information you want about these projects.

Once you have understood what the metric will be used for, and how the task ratings relate to each other (linear increasing difficulty vs. categorical distinctions) then there are plenty of simple metrics that may codify this analysis.

For example, you may rate projects for risk based on a combination of the number of unknown tasks and the number of tasks with difficulty above a certain threshold. Alternatively you may rate projects for duration based on a weighted sum of task difficulty, using a default or estimated difficulty for unknown tasks.